# Enabling CORS Spring issue with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, cors

I need to enable CORS for `Spring` application that uses `Spring Security` and it is not working. I am making `GET` request from `http://localhost:3000` (which is node.js server) to `http://localhost:8080` (which is Tomcat server).

I tried the following approaches but can not make any of them work:
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

[Spring Data Rest and Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724994/spring-data-rest-and-cors?rq=1)

https://gist.github.com/zeroows/80bbe076d15cb8a4f0ad

[Enabling CORS using Spring Boot 1.3.3-RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931529/enabling-cors-using-spring-boot-1-3-3-release)

[Spring CORS controller annotation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140706/spring-cors-controller-annotation-not-working)

Currently I have a `@Controller`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/views")
public class LoginController{

@Autowired
private EventService eventService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/companies", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
    public String listCompanies(Model model) {
        String companiesList = eventService.getCompanies();
        return companiesList;
    }
}
```

And `AppConfig` file where I have been unsuccessfully trying to allow `CORS`:

```
@EnableWebMvc 
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

I want to somehow get the `json` from the `listCompanies` method in my `Angular2` app. I am getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` error, so I suppose it is `CORS` issue.

Comment: Can you try adding allowedMethods("\*") like registry.addMapping("/**"). allowedMethods("\*");

Comment: Giving the same error in browser. In Eclipse's console I see `Access is denied (user is anonymous)`. I have Spring Security login there, so probably it is trying to redirect me to login page.

Comment: I just need a solution for local development, not for production, so if Spring Security is causing the issue, then to disallow it somehow might solve it, but I do not know how (and it should not be too many changes since it will make local development worse)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and fixed it with custom filter as described in documentation: [27.5 Filter based CORS support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_filter_based_cors_support)

Basically, you need to create filter:

```
public class MyCorsFilter extends CorsFilter {

    public MyCorsFilter() {
        super(configurationSource());
    }

    private static UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }

}
```

and then add it in web.xml (or corresponding java based config) before `springSecurityFilterChain` like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.configuration.cors.MyCorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also have `dispatchOptionsRequest` (which is not necessary according to the new documentation):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
    <!-- "OPTIONS" method support -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you defined somewhere the allowed origines in spring configuration? `http://localhost:8080`

```
@EnableWebMvc 
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
        .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

Look at chapter 27.3 of official docs to enable global CORS configuration : 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html

If you don't need to include cookies on cross-origin request, replace `.allowCredentials(true)` by `.allowCredentials(false)`

Comment: I edited my post. The origin must be localhost:3000 (your node server), not localhost:8080. Otherwise you can try with the * wilcard but it's not recommanded for production!

Comment: That's the issue: it seems like when we have Spring Security and want to enable CORS, smth weird is going on and regular ways of enabling it are not working because I tried virtually everything I could find on the Internet. Hours of trying this and that lead me nowhere. Maybe some things work for enabling CORS however Spring Security issues authentication issues and is trying to redirect me to login page. Still in that case I am seeing this CORS error on the front end, it is the same always, no matter what is the output in the console in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
   import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

/**
 * Enabling CORS support  - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
 * 
 * 
 * <code>
    <!-- Add this to your web.xml to enable "CORS" -->
    <filter>
      <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.elm.mb.rest.filters.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
 * </code>
 */
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            LOG.trace("Sending Header....");
            // CORS "pre-flight" request
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
//          response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.